# Webots - Check if point is inside the object

Tags: c++, bounding-box, webots

I am using an algorithm to generate points my robot is supposed to explore. To do this, these points have to be generated such that none of them are within the area that obstacles occupy. How can that be done by using Webots?

I cannot use collision detection methods like `dWebotsGetContactJointGroup()` because the robot doesnt collide with the object. I want to find if a point is within the area that the object occupies on the ground, before sending the robot to explore that point.

Is there a way to check if a given point is within a `Solid` or `Bounding Object` of a `Node`? How can I do this in webots using C++.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to show some code for context.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the Supervisor (https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor) to import a Solid node with a small sphere as bounding object and then check if this sphere does collide any other solid node (using the supervisor API too: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor#wb_supervisor_node_get_contact_point).